# How can I rescale normalized standard deviation in scikit-learn's Gaussian process regression?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, normalization, standard-deviation, gaussian-process

I am using scikit-learn for modeling with Gaussian Process Regression. My data are not normalized. The model always return standard deviation values between 0 and 1, which is not in line with my data. How can I rescale standard deviation values to get the actual standard deviation?

Comment: Can you share an example code with an example dataset? the output and expected output would help others to answer your question in a better way.

Comment: It is possible that you are not using the Constant kernel to accommodate the variance. Without it, the RBF kernel will return values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

One way I'm using is using standard scaler in scikit-learn. It'd be natural to normalize your datset before training your model.

The process is as follows:

- fit scaler with your training data (denote scaler as SC)
- transform your dataset (training and test set with SC)
- train your GPR model with the normalized training set
- predict your the normalized test set with GPR model and get output
- inverse transform your mean and std output with SC

Here's a [link to std_scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)